# “uninitialized class variable @@columns_cache” error during migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, database-migration, rails-migrations

So i'm having migration to remove unnecessary columns

```
[:table_name_1, :table_name_2, :table_name_3, :table_name_4].each do |tables|
  remove_column tables, :column_name_here
end
```

When i'm using

```
rake db:migrate --trace
```

I'm getting something like this

```
 ==  RemoveColumntsFromDB: migrating ========================================
    -- remove_column(:table_name_1, :column_name_here)
    rake aborted!
    An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

    uninitialized class variable @@columns_cache in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:936:in `clear_table_columns_cache'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1143:in `remove_column'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `send'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `method_missing'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
    C:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
```

Does any have idea why?

Comment: Please edit the question and include the error message in the text body. This prevents link rot and you shouldn't expect ppl to have to go somewhere else to get the gist of your question.

Comment: Yeah, i know. Thank you. I just can't insert full error here because of an error too much code", so posted cutted version of it.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the database adapter, have you tried updating? Also Ruby 1.87 was EOL:Ed in 2014 and so you definitely need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

That was an issue with database.

It was used for sessions instead of the cookie-based default because highly confidential information.

So `rake db:sessions:create` fixed it.